# Does core data delete objects with cascading delete rules instantly or on-save?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, cascading-deletes

In a Core Data model, entity A has a relation to entity B with the delete rule set to `Cascade`. Is object B immediately deleted when the `[context deleteObject:A]` is called, or does Core Data wait for the [context save:&error] method, like it does with object validation?

I'm wondering if after deleting A, I could create an object C that would then search for B in the context and establish the relation. Would that prevent B from being deleted?

Cheers,
Eric-Paul.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Deleted" is merely a state. How that state is persisted when the user (or your app) saves is an implementation detail. It can still be undone after a save if the file hasn't been closed and its state lost.

If your intention is to move the B instances of an A instance to another instance of A, you need to change the relationship *before* you delete the first A instance, else the cascade rule will take the Bs with it (per the exact definition of the rule's behavior). Once deleted (whether directly or by a cascade rule), it's deleted. Searches won't reveal deleted Bs.

So: if you want to preserve an A's Bs, assign the Bs to another A before deleting the original. Otherwise, you'll need to create new Bs for the new A.

Comment: Nice, my C objects can't precede deletion of A, but now I know I have to manually take care of the relationships to prevent deletion. Thanks!

Comment: Or, seen another way, you could just not use a cascade rule and delete the Bs in code if that's actually a special case. If the most usual route is moving the Bs to another A, then you're handling this in code anyway.